# Possible to switch to a specific page of the home screen when "Driving" focus activates on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, automation, focus

I have set up some filters for notifications and calls and such when I'm out driving, and my iPhone enters the Driving focus.

What I would also like is for the phone to automatically switch to a specific page of the home screen with apps that I use during driving, such as map apps, parking apps, shortcuts to start intenet radio, etc.

Basically, the full goal I would like to have is:

- When the phone connects to the car Bluetooth, it enters driving mode (this works now), and it switches to a custom home page with apps used during driving
- When the phone later disconnects, it goes back to the first home page with all my usual apps

The things I've looked for:

- The Driving focus does not allow me to control which home screen pages are available, like focus modes that I create myself
- Setting up a shortcut automation can be done, but there doesn't seem to be any action that I can use to change which page is currently active
- Creating a separate custom driving focus, and using shortcut automation to switch to that when the phone enters the built-in driving focus would give me half of what I want, but the phone would then be stuck on this custom driving focus until I take it out manually. The built-in driving focus stops automatically when the phone disconnects from Bluetooth.
- Creating a shortcut automation to temporarily switch from the built-in driving focus to a custom driving focus with limited pages, and then switch back, works in terms of getting to the right page, as well as leaving the phone in the built-in mode with the normal automation. However, since that shortcut now made the phone (re-)enter built-in driving mode, the automation would start all over again, making the temporary adjustment and then running over and over and over again.

What I hope is that I missed something simple. Does anyone know if I did?

Comment: You should consider that this needs to be run from Siri. Depending on where you live, it is now illegal to even touch your phone whilst driving. This is true for most of the EU & nearby countries.

Comment: You're correct that the system does not allow a custom lock screen for driving focus, and that appears to be a conscious decision on Apple's part, so it's unlikely a bug report will get that changed. Nevertheless I will file one because I've also wanted to do something like this

Comment: And @Tetsujin this is an attempt to replicate CarPlay/head-unit layouts for people who don't have it. Because we're making our drive safer with things like these, I personally don't really care about the letter of the law-just the spirit.

Using the Music app in Car Play is just as dangerous as on my phone, which is why I try not to do either while driving. Having the Music app readily available makes it easy to do quickly while stopped.

Comment: Lastly, Siri refuses to do some things while in driving mode, which makes it kinda useless. This includes setting a driving focus, amazingly

Comment: @Ezekiel - "Car Play is just as dangerous as on my phone" How's that? I don't have to let go of the steering wheel at all to control carplay, many of the controls are on the wheel itself, the rest on Siri.

Comment: @Tetsujin For skipping to the next track, sure - but that's not CarPlay - same benefit from Bluetooth connection. But if you want to pick a new song or something and you don't use Siri, CarPlay is just an optimized screen that some of us can't afford to put in our older cars